# PyQt: Emit signal when cell entered in QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots, qcalendarwidget

In my Qt application I'm using  the `QCalendarWidget` and I would like to get notified when the mouse enters a new cell of the calendar. I know that the `QCalendarWidget` is using a `QTableView` internally which inherits from [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html) and this has an `entered` signal:

> This signal is emitted when the mouse cursor enters the item specified
>   by index. Mouse tracking needs to be enabled for this feature to work.

I tried to receive the signal with following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyCalendar:

    def __init__(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = QMainWindow()
        cal = QCalendarWidget(window)

        window.resize(320, 240)
        cal.resize(320, 240)

        table = cal.findChild(QTableView)
        table.setMouseTracking(True)
        table.entered.connect(self.onCellEntered)

        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def onCellEntered(self, index):
        print("CellEntered")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyCalendar()
```

But my callback function is never called. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: It would be nice if you expanded your code into a small example that can be run and shows the problem.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly I have updated the code in the question with a working window application which shows a `QCalendarWidget` but the `onCellEntered` method is never called although the signal is connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QCalendarWidget` class uses a custom table-view which bypasses the normal mouse-event handlers - so the `enetered` signal never gets emitted. However, it is possible to work-around that by using an event-filter to emit a custom signal that does the same thing.

Here is a demo script that implements that:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    cellEntered = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.calendar = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.calendar)
        self._table = self.calendar.findChild(QtGui.QTableView)
        self._table.setMouseTracking(True)
        self._table.installEventFilter(self)
        self._index = None
        self.cellEntered.connect(self.handleCellEntered)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source is self._table:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
                index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(
                    source.indexAt(event.pos()))
                if index != self._index:
                    self._index = index
                    self.cellEntered.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(index))
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self._index = None
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def handleCellEntered(self, index):
        print(index.row(), index.column())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wow thank you for that answer! How did you find out this all?

Comment: @Cilenco. No big secret. I've been using PyQt since 2004/5, so just a steady accumulation of knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

I've investigated a bit and I think I know why this happens.

`QCalendarWidget` creates a private subclass of `QTableView` called `QCalendarView` and instantiates it as a child of itself. (This instance is called `qt_calendar_calendarview`.)

If you look at [`QCalendarView`'s code (Qt 5)](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qcalendarwidget.cpp#n1500), you'll see this:

```
void QCalendarView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    [...]
    if (!calendarModel) {
        QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
        return;
    }
    [...]
}
```

This means only if there is no `calendarModel`, the superclasses `mouseMoveEvent`is called which is responsible for emitting the `entered` signal. All of this is an implementation detail of `QCalendarWidget, so it's probably best not to rely on any of this anyway.

---

So for a way around this, I'm not sure what the best approach is. You'll have to catch the event *before* it gets to the table. This can be done using `QObject.installEventFilter()` or re-implementing `QWidget.mouseMoveEvent()`, but then you don't get the model index directly. You could probably use `QAbstractItemView.indexAt()` for this purpose.